# UILabel cutting off text

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uilabel

I have a bit of a strange problem. I have a UITableView controller. Inside the UITableViewCells are four profile images for the user and below each picture is a UILabel to display the name. All the labels are the same size and all the constraints are equally set up. The maximum username length is 12 characters and it displays this correctly, not text cut. I have one username though that is also 12 characters long and it is cutting off 3 characters. It should surely fit if all the other 12 character names do. Could anyone give me any pointers to why this might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to use a limit for the number of characters as reference for the width of a label. Unless you're using a monospaced font like Courier, you will not have the same width on all words with the same number of letters. For example, the string "llllll" is usually (depending on font) much shorter than "oooooo" and they both have 6 characters

Comment: what is an problem user name? How to help without info?... 
maybe you have a \n symbol inside it or space and it goes to second line or some unprintable characters...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, unless you use a monospaced font, 12 characters are going o occupy a varying amount of space.

The easiest thing to do in this case is to set the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` to `YES`. This will scale the text so that it fits the width of its container.